# Cannot find symbol: method add

Tags: java

Why am I receiving the following error: `cannot find symbol: method add`? This is my code:

```
import java.util.*

public class ArrayList {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    public void processinput(String s) {
        int[] a = { 34, 25, 16, 98, 77, 101, 24 };

        ArrayList b = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int d = a[i];
            if (d % 2 > 0) {
                b.add(new Integer(d));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(b.get(i) + " ");
        }

        for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Your code compiles for me (if I put it inside a method in a class, obviously). Do you possibly have a class named `ArrayList` somewhere? If so you might accidentally using that instead of `java.util.ArrayList`, which you probably meant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot find symbol-method add (java.lang.integer)..whats the problem actually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801711/cannot-find-symbol-method-add-java-lang-integer-whats-the-problem-actually)

Answer (score 3):

Reading your question again, I assume you are missing

```
import java.util.*;
```

at the start of your class. This is the only way you could be getting this error. BTW you should also be getting an error like "Cannot resolve symbol ArrayList" which tells you what the problem is.

---

Change the last loop to be

```
for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

With experience you will be able to read error messages and understand what they mean. In this case

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
at Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

On line 33, (or what ever it is in your code) you tried to accessed an index which is beyond the end of the array.  The last element of array `a` is `a.length-1` because the first element is `0`

It is important to read error message carefully because they are often the best clue as to what the problem is and how to fix it.

When you post a question you should post the error you are getting.

Comment: It's not very visible from the post, but he's actually fighting a compiler error at the moment.

Comment: @Joachim, I got that from your comment.  I think its a missing import and he's not reading all the error messages. ;)

Comment: I vote for the missing (or wrong) import. (and for your answer ;) )

Comment: If you see a follow up question, the OP has named the class ArrayList. ;) Didn't see that one comming.

Answer (score 1):

There is [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html): 7 .  fix this line

```
for(int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class is called `ArrayList`, and this is hiding `java.util.ArrayList`, hence your compilation errors. Either change the name of your class, or use the full name of `java.util.ArrayList` when declaring `b`.