# cannot find symbol-method add (java.lang.integer)..whats the problem actually?

Tags: java

```
public class ArrayList
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    public void processinput (String s)
    {
        int[] a = {34, 25, 16, 98, 77, 101, 24};

        ArrayList  b = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            int d = a[i];
            if(d%2 > 0) {
               b.add(new Integer(d));
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(b.get(i) + " ");
        }

        for(int i = a.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code could use some work beyond just fixing the compiler error.  You should probably be using `ArrayList<Integer>` rather than `ArrayList`, since that way you get all the benefits of type-checking.  You don't need to explicitly wrap up the integer `d` with `new Integer(d)`; autoboxing will do this for you.  Finally, the code in the last for loop will immediately cause an out of bounds exception, since index `a.length` in array `a` will never succeed.  You probably want to set `i = a.length - 1.`

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't simply [edit your first question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792325/java-programming)?

Answer (score 2):

Notice **package** of class: Your `ArrayList` is not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Correct:

```
java.util.ArrayList b = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in naming your class as `ArrayList`. In your `ArrayList` class you do not have a method defined as `add()`. You are invoking your package `ArrayList` not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Change the declaration to `java.util.List<Integer> b = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>();`. Also for clarity rename your class to something meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for formatting Joachim. I wrote the answer from my iPad and unfortunately the formatting options do not show up on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't run code but at a glance I see that you start with `a.length` which will cause [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). fix this line like `a.length - 1`

```
for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
}
```

and this line

```
ArrayList<Integer>  b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: it works for me. Change your className. and fix these line it will work